# How renew greenlock-express certificates forcefully at any time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, lets-encrypt, greenlock

I have CA certificates files in "greenlock.d/live/URL_PATH/". It's expiration date is Aug 2022.

But I want to renew them right now to check whether they are renewing or not. Please suggest me how can I renew them at any time?

### What I have done:

I have tried number of solutions like:

- Tried Some commands
- Changing renewal time ("renewAt") in "greenlock.d/config.json"

### Code:

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

var app = function(req, res) {
    res.end('Hello, Encrypted World!');
};

module.exports = app;
```

**server.js**

```
'use strict';

var beapp = require('./app.js');

require('greenlock-express')
    .init({
        packageRoot: __dirname,
        maintainerEmail: "EMAIL_ID",
        configDir: './greenlock.d',
        cluster: true
    })
    // .serve(beapp);
    .ready(httpsWorker);
function httpsWorker(glx) {
    var httpsServer = glx.httpsServer(null, beapp);
    httpsServer.listen(443, "0.0.0.0", function () {
        console.info("Listening on ", httpsServer.address());
    });
}
```

**greenlock.d/config.json**

```
{
  "defaults": {
    "store": {
      "basePath": "./greenlock.d",
      "module": "greenlock-store-fs"
    },
    "challenges": {
      "http-01": {
        "module": "acme-http-01-standalone"
      }
    },
    "renewOffset": "-45d",
    "renewStagger": "3d",
    "accountKeyType": "EC-P256",
    "serverKeyType": "RSA-2048",
    "subscriberEmail": "EMAIL_ID"
  },
  "sites": [
    {
      "subject": "URL_PATH",
      "altnames": [
        "URL_PATH"
      ],
      "renewAt": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Run these commands sequencially:

> 1. npm init
> 2. npm install --save greenlock-express@v4
> 3. npx greenlock init --config-dir ./greenlock.d --maintainer-email
>    'jon@example.com'
> 4. npx greenlock add --subject example.com --altnames example.com
> 5. node server.js

Reference : https://www.npmjs.com/package/greenlock-express#1-create-your-project